# What will be the regex for an alphanumeric that should not be less than 9 digits after excluding leading zeros?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to build a regex where an alphanumeric value:

1. Special characters are not allowed
2. 0 or blank spaces are not allowed
3. Alphanumeric characters allowed
4. Length of the value should not be less than 9 digits after excluding leading zeros

I tried `^0|[A-Za-z1-9]{9}$` but this doesn't fit in what I actually want.

Can anybody help me out on this?

Comment: ^0|[A-Za-z1-9]{9}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost right. The regex `^0*[1-9a-zA-Z]{9,}$` might be the one you're looking for.

It says basically: "Any text starting with or without leading zeros followed by at least nine alphanumeric characters excluding `0`".

Answer (score 1):

```
final String PAT = "0*[A-Za-z1-9]{9,}";
```

is what you need from the description I believe

Comment: The quantifier applies to that only and not the leading zero stuff

Comment: Actually you're right - I confused myself there ;) I'll remove it